# Not able to install jq on mac using macports module

Tags: macos, ansible, jq, macports

I am trying to install jq on mac using ansible-playbook. I have used Macports module available in ansible to achieve this task
Playbook-snippet

```
 - name: install items
      macports:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      with_items:
        - jq
        - openjdk11
        - nodejs12
        - git
```

When I run this playbook the play is success and when I check for jq installation using command "jq --version" seeing command not found error, whereas other items like git and java are installed. Facing this issue only for nodejs and jq.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have failed to include the macports directory in your PATH, since macOS ships with a `git` binary (although it's usually just a shim to install the Xcode Command Line Tools), and likely the same story with `java`

Of course, since your question didn't include one byte of output or troubleshooting text, it's just a theory